# PowerShell Error: The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I am trying to get the sharepoint's site template but everytime I run my ps script

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials $Cred

$web = Get-PnpWeb
Write-Host "Test Connect: ", $web.Title

$template = Get-PnPSiteTemplate -OutputInstance
Write-Output $template

Disconnect-PnPOnline
```

It produces this error.

```
Test Connect:  Test demo1
Get-PnPSiteTemplate: /Users/user1/shell scripts/test.ps1:29:13                                                         
Line |                                                                                                                  
  29 |  $template = Get-PnPSiteTemplate -OutputInstance                                                                 
     |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                 
     | The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32. Path: $.position.sectionIndex | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 107.
```

Also, I am running this on a MacOS with Visual Studio Code. Already installed the PowerShell https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-macos?view=powershell-7.3

I don't know how relevant this is. I have tried to install the .Net Framework

```
user1@Mac-mini shell scripts % dotnet --list-sdks                                                   
3.1.425 [/Users/user1/shell scripts/dotnet/sdk]
6.0.403 [/Users/user1/shell scripts/dotnet/sdk]
7.0.100 [/Users/user1/shell scripts/dotnet/sdk]
```

I still got the same error

Comment: maybe this will help https://github.com/pnp/powershell/discussions/2421

Comment: Thank you @Metzli_Tonaltzintli. Use `Get-PnPSiteTemplate -ExcludeHandlers PageContents` to remove the issue.